# Define rewardsum instance for pettingzooenv in torchrl

Tags: pytorch, pettingzoo

I'd like to define `rewardsum()` instance for pettingzoo env wrapper in torchrl.

here is the definition of my env:

```
from torchrl.envs.libs.pettingzoo import PettingZooEnv
from torchrl.envs.utils import MarlGroupMapType

env = PettingZooEnv(
    task="mpe/simple_spread_v3",
    parallel=False,
    use_mask=True, # Must use it since one player plays at a time
    group_map=None # # Use default for AEC (one group per player)
)
```

what I am trying to do:

```
env = TransformedEnv(
    env,
    RewardSum(),
    
)

check_env_specs(env)
```

here is the error i get (split into multiple lines):

```
ValueError: Could not match the env reset_keys ['_reset'] with 
            the in_keys [('agent_0', 'reward'), ('agent_1', 'reward'),
            ('agent_2', 'reward')].
            Please make sure that these have the same length.
```

I am expecting the sum of the rewards of all agents in my env to be accessible via `["next", "episode_reward"]` which are default access keys defined by torchrl.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the issue is that the environment has a global done state but there is a different reward key for each group.

`RewardSum(reset_keys=["_reset"] * len(env.group_map.keys())` should work